# PayPal Payment transfer confirmation API

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, paypal

I want to know that when anyone user of PayPal send money to my PayPal account so how can I check in my App that I received money? Is there any API which returns me that i received Payment in my PayPal account?

Comment: Hi, Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536360/checking-if-paypal-payment-was-successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is Paypal IPN (instant payment notificatiion) and PDT (payment data transfer)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/